# MYSQL - Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a temporaryTable in a stored procedure with the following code:

```
   DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testprocedure 

AS

BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Best_MitarbeiterLieferant 
(`enter code here`
    angestellter VARCHAR (50),
    AnzahlBestellungen INT NOT NULL,
    Lieferant VARCHAR(50)

)
#Test Datensatz
INSERT INTO Best_MitarbeiterLieferant VALUES ('Stefan', 12, 'UPS')
#Testabfrage
SELECT * FROM Best_MitarbeiterLieferant

# Tabelle wieder löschen
DROP TABLE Best_MitarbeiterLieferant
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

But I am getting an error, and I don't know how to solve it. Appreciate help!

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS BEGIN CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Best_MitarbeiterLieferant  (
>       angeste' at line 3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testprocedure()
BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Best_MitarbeiterLieferant 
(   
    angestellter VARCHAR (50),
    AnzahlBestellungen INT NOT NULL,
    Lieferant VARCHAR(50)

);

#Test Datensatz
INSERT INTO Best_MitarbeiterLieferant VALUES ('Stefan', 12, 'UPS');
#Testabfrage
SELECT * FROM Best_MitarbeiterLieferant;

# Tabelle wieder löschen
DROP TABLE Best_MitarbeiterLieferant;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: :Hey, this one worked out. I was about to try it with the ; but mysql told me "unexpected symbol" but it works! thank you for the super fast answer!

Comment: i will accept this as an answer, when it's available. Thank you!